# Storing array input using react admin without ArrayInput

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-admin

I was wondering if it was possible to input array data without using ArrayInput.
My data structure is the following:

```
{ id,
  data: {
         oilPrice: {day, price}[],
         gasPrice: {day, price}[],
         }
}
```

On the create page I am showing a user a MUI Select component with choices Oil or Gas.
Under which I am displaying a calendar. When a user clicks on a date a field for entering the price is shown.
Sample display: user chooses Oil, clicks on 05.05.2022 and enters price 500.
Then they choose a date 06.06.2022 and enter price 550.
So how do I save the data as

```
{ id,
  data: {
         oilPrice: [ {05.05.2022, 500}, {06.06.2022, 550}]
         }
}
```

The issue is also persisting the previously entered data while the user clicks around and enters new values.
I know this is a difficult and unusual case, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

React-admin doesn't provide a built-in component for that use case. You'll have to write your own Input component using react-hook-form hooks.

Pointers:

- [react-admin custom input doc](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#writing-your-own-input-component)
- [react-hook-form usecontroller doc](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/)